# How do you measure capacity without a constant current? (coulomb counting?)

Tags: batteries, nimh, capacity

What would be the most accurate (but not too expensive) method to find the capacity of NiMH battery cells when you are not able to use a constant current? Would using coulomb counting work or is that just for finding the SoC of a battery when the capacity and previous SoC is known and just using a sensor or shunt resistor for measuring the current (I think it could work both ways)?

Comment: Sure thing. Coulumb counting is just a more fancy name of integration of current measurement.

Comment: Some "fuel gauge" IC's for lithium cells do exactly this.  Likely to be available for NiMH also.

Comment: Coulomb counting works, but accuracy suffers as the battery ages and the internal impedance rises.  You can have cheap, simple, and fair accuracy, or expensive, more complicated and good accuracy.